# Is there a way to interact with Mac Applications with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, user-interface

I am trying to interact (i.e. clicking buttons within app, taking keyboard input and typing for me, etc.) with the Cisco AnyConnect Client, specifically.  
However, I would like to know if there is way that is viable with Python 3 to interact with any other Mac applications.

Comment: `pyautogui` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using PyAutoGUI like @Mark Setchell stated